# Replace and upper case in a snippet with vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'd like to replace `Context` in `myAppContext` and upper case on tab pressing, so the end result should be `MyApp`.

I would rather do it all at once. Here's where I started.:

To remove 'Context' I can do  `${1/Context//}`
and for uppercase: `${1/(^[a-z])/${1:/upcase}/}`.

What is the best way to combine these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
${1/^([a-z])|Context/${1:/upcase}/g}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/APtpGN/1/).

Here, `^([a-z])|Context` matches either a lowercase ASCII letter at the start of the string (capturing it into Group 1) or a `Context` substring, and replaces the match with the uppercased Group 1 value (which will be empty if `Context` matches.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `capitalize` transform this is very easy:

`${1/(.*)Context/${1:/capitalize}/}`

Just capitalize everything before `Context` - `capitalize` only works on the first letter anyway.  No need for a `g` flag.